# TLS Пассивный отпечаток

Tags: веб-программирование, tls, fingerprint

Могут ли сайты использовать снятие отпечатка TLS как дополнительный способ детекта пользователей? Обычно TLS отпечаток используется для блокировки ботов, так как позволяет отличить полноценный браузер от другого ПО. Если мы возьмём во внимание конкретный настоящий браузер (например Google Chrome), существует ли возможность отличить одного пользователя от другого с помощью этого метода? Насколько уникален TLS отпечаток отдельного браузера? Зависит ли он от конкретной версии браузера, версии ОС или же только от настроек TLS в системе?

Если данный метод действительно можно использовать не только для определения типа ПО (браузер/не браузер), но и детекта пользователей, каким образом можно изменить TLS отпечаток браузера (например Google Chrome в Windows 10)? Догадываюсь, что только через системные настройки.

Answer (score 1):

Ну-у-у-у, я бы сказал, TLS Fingerprint - это шаманское гадание на кофейной гуще.

Пытаться угадать браузер по тому, сколько ciphersuites он использует, какие эллиптические кривые предлагает в ClientHello... Возможно, пока ботоделы не обращают на эти параметры внимание, и боты действительно отличаются от реальных пользователей, но со временем они спохватятся и научатся мимикрировать под реальные браузеры.

Что же касается различий между пользователями, то набор криптографических параметров может зависеть от версии браузера и версии операционной системы (если браузер пользуется системными библиотеками), но никак не связан с персоной, которая пользуется браузером. Поэтому если весь офис пользуется компьютерами с одной версией ОС (обновляемой централизованно) и одной и той же версией браузера, то различить работников такого офиса по криптографическим параметрам ИМХО невозможно.